# SQL Bulk move from one table to another

Tags: sql, database, select, insert

So I need help with some SQL work I'm doing. I am not the best at SQL, and I have come across an issue that I need some guidance. I want to split a table I have into smaller tables. There are some rows in there that don't belong and I want to move them.

The two tables will have the exact same columns and schema.

I know I can do something like:

```
Insert into [table1]
Select * From [table2]
```

The problem that arises is there are 100,000,000+ rows to move. The RowID's for these 100,000,000+ are not in order. Otherwise I would just have

```
Insert into [table1]
    Select * From [table2]
    Where RowID > x AND RowID <= x + y
```

and iterate until all rows were copied.

I know there are loops that can be done, but so far they have been inefficient. I understand this will take longer than 10 minutes, and most likely will take some time. I just need some guidance.

I'm not settled on using just SQL code. If there is a wizard I can use with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to do this, I'm good with that. I've looked into BULK INSERT and don't quite understand that fully, so an explanation on that would be fine.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say they are "not in order" do you mean that they are not a sequence (regardless of their actual order in the database)?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is it - have a look at the link below. I have some notes I can dig out for you.

Comment: @web_bod - its SQL 2010. I'll take a look thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to partition your tables - there's an [introduction/tutorial](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Partitioning)

It's a pretty hefty bit of work.